# Free abelian groups are not divisible

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Is the following true?

$G$ is a torsion free abelian group of rank $>n$.

Let $S$ be be a subgroup of $G$ generated by $s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n$.

(1) If $m_1s_1+m_2s_2+ ...+m_ns_n$ is linearly independent modulo $p$ for every prime $p$, then $S$ is linearly independent. That is, if $m_1s_1+m_2s_2+ ...+m_ns_n=0$ implies $m_i =0$  (mod $p)$ for all $i$ and every prime $p$, then $m_1s_1+m_2s_2+ ...+m_ns_n=0$ implies $m_i=0$ for all $i$.

(2) Free abelian groups are never divisible.

How do I go about proving statement (2) above? Any hints will greatly be appreciated. thanks

Comment: What is $G$ supposed to be? (The second statement follows directly from the universal property of free abelian groups. If the first statement means what I think it means, you'll have an easier time proving the contrapositive.)

Comment: -1: I can't parse condition (1), even if $G$ is meant to be an abelian group: I don't what a "linearly independent abelian group" is.  As for (2): can you prove that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not divisible?  Can you reduce to this case?  Finally, the title is just about maximally unhelpful.

Comment: Sorry for the unhelpful title and unclear question that i have let you all suffer on. I was in a hurry to go out and forgot to state the question clearly. Now i have edited it. Please take a look at it.

Comment: you are still not stating the condition correctly. You mean to say that if $\{ s_1, ... s_n \}$ is linearly independent $\bmod p$ for all $p$ then it is linearly independent in $G$. (But now that you've stated the rest of it in so much detail, shouldn't it be obvious? If the condition holds for all $p$ then the $m_i$ are integers divisible by all primes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1:

**Definition:** Suppose *G* is an abelian group, and *S* is a subset of *G* generating the group *H*.  For each prime p, the group *H*/*pH* is a vector space over the field **Z**/*p***Z** of *p* elements.  Consider the set *S* + *pH* = { *s* + *pH* : *s* in *S* } in the group *H*/*pH*.  We say that *S* is **linearly independent mod *p*** if *S* + *pH* is a linearly independent set in the vector space *H*/*pH* over **Z**/*p***Z**.

**Proposition:** Suppose *G* is an abelian group, and *S* is a subset of *G* that is linearly independent mod *p* for every prime *p*.  Then *S* is a basis of a free abelian subgroup of *G*.

**Proof:** Suppose Σ *a<sub>s</sub> s* = 0 for some integers *a<sub>s</sub>*. Then reducing the equation mod *p* produces a linear dependence relation in the vector space *H*/*pH*.  Hence each *a<sub>s</sub>* ≡ 0 mod *p*, by the definition of linearly independent.  In particular, *a<sub>s</sub>* is an integer divisible by every prime *p*.  The only such integer is 0, and *a<sub>s</sub>* = 0 for all *s* in *S*.  This means that *S* is "independent", as in, it is a basis of the free abelian subgroup it spans. □

As far as I can tell, you don't need to assume *G* is torsion-free (but, the subgroup generated by *S* is torsion-free), and you don't need to assume *S* is finite.  Note that no subgroup can possibly by linearly independent mod *p* according to my definition.  You want a **subset** *S*, not a subgroup, even though you really are quite interested in the subgroup *H* it generates.

---

Part 2:

This is sort of a restatement of the previous part.

**Proposition:** Let *G* be a free abelian group with basis *S*.  Then no element of *S* is divisible by any prime number *p*.

**Proof:** Suppose *x* in *S* is divisible by *p*, that is, suppose there is some *y* in *G* such that *py* = *x*.  Write *y* as a linear combination of *S*: *y* = Σ *a<sub>s</sub> s*.  Then *x* = *py* = Σ (*pa<sub>s</sub>*) *s*.  Since *S* is a basis, the coefficients are uniquely determined and so we get 1 = *pa<sub>x</sub>* and 0 = *pa<sub>s</sub>* for *s* ≠ *x*, *s* in *S*.  These are just equations of integers, and canceling *p* one gets *a<sub>x</sub>* is the "integer" 1/*p*, a contradiction. □